# Runnable with progressdialog crash

Tags: progressdialog, runnable

The code below is where the error is coming from. What I wanted is to bring up the `loginDialog1` after `loginRedirectCheck` is true. But instead of showing the `progressDialog`, the application crash. Am I doing anything wrong? How can I fix it? Thank you.

```java
Runnable myRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(loginCheck){
            if(loginRedirectCheck){
                loginCheck = false;
                new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        loginDialog1.show();
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
};

Thread myThread = new Thread(myRunnable);
myThread.start();
```

Comment: is this Eclipse RCP? You need to stick to the UI Thread.

What does "application crashes" mean? An application does not simply crash, there must be an exception. find it.

Comment: it is eclipse IDE, stick to ui thread in this case refers to onCreate?

Comment: the exception is abandon: SurfaceTexture?

Answer (score 0):

> Am I doing anything wrong?

Yes, you are creating the `Handler` inside of your new thread. That causes its posted `Runnables` to be executed there which leads to an execution of `loginDialog1.show();` inside the new thread but I guess it has to be executed in the UI-Thread.

> How can I fix it?

Create your handler inside your UI-Thread (for example as instance variable of your object containing the `myThrad.start()`) and `post()` your runnable to that handler instead of a newly created one.

EDIT:

I think in your case a final local variable would be fine:

```java
final Handler myHandler = new Handler();

Runnable myRunnable = new Runnable() {
 [...]
                loginCheck = false;
                myHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
 [...]
```

Comment: in that case he could also just remove the outside Runnable and use the "new Handler(). ..." part.

Comment: Good point though it depends a little on whether he really showed us all his code or what else the thread is for... nevertheless I agree he should consider that.